# update part of a value of a json object using JQ

Tags: json, shell, jq, substitution

Have a value inside a JSON object with a variable that needs to be updated using JQ, below is my son file and jq command I'm using to update **accountid** in json file

```
{"bucketname":"test/$accountid/123","objectname":"test/$accountid/123","targetlocation":"$TARGET_LOCATION"}
```

**JQ Command**

```
jq 'map(.$accountid = "123")' myjson.json
```

**Error**

```
jq: error (at myjson.json:1): Cannot index string with string "$accountid"
```

I'm I missing something here?

Comment: Is `accountid` a substring you want to replace, and not e.g. a key name? Your JSON has no `accountid` key.

Comment: @thatotherguy accountid is part of a key value that I wanted to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it would appear you should be using `map_values` and perhaps something like `sub`. Consider therefore this example:

```
echo '{"bucketname":"test/$accountid/123","objectname":"test/$accountid/123","targetlocation":"$TARGET_LOCATION"}' |
 jq 'map_values( sub("[$]accountid";"123") )'
```

produces:

```
{
  "bucketname": "test/123/123",
  "objectname": "test/123/123",
  "targetlocation": "$TARGET_LOCATION"
}
```

### Sharpening

You might want to sharpen the criteria for substituion, e.g.

```
sub("[$]accountid(?<tail>(/|$))"; "123\(.tail)" )
```

Comment: I tried this `echo myjson.json | jq 'map_values( sub("[$]accountid";"123") )'` but return error `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0`

Comment: `cat myjson.json | jq 'map_values( sub("[$]accountid";"124") )'` this works!!